# Saving a workbook in two different drive locations

Tags: excel, vba

I have code which saves a document to a different saving location with a different file name.

I have now been asked to save this in an additional save location (so two separate save locations) but I cannot amend the code to do so.

I have tried duplicating the code which obviously didn't work, and adding in both save locations, but the doc was saved in the latter location rather than both. I still need the code which saves it as a certain naming convention.

Thanks in advance!

```
'save workbook with different naming convention
Dim dt, wbSource, wbNam, wbDest As String
wbSource = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
wbNam = "Plan_"
dt = Format((Now), "yyyy_mm_dd  hmmAM/PM")
wbDest = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "C:\workbook location" & wbNam & dt & ".xlsm"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=wbDest
Workbooks.Open Filename:=wbSource
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
```

Comment: `wbDest = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "C:\workbook location"` This makes no sense. You are concatenating two paths. `ActiveWorkbook.Path` will return something like `C:/MainFolder/FolderwithWorkbook` and you are concatenating that text with `"C:\workbook location"`

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault, typo! The ActiveWorkbook.Path should not have been there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like the following

```
Dim dt As String, wbNam As String, wbDest1 As String, wbDest2 As String
Dim j As Long

wbNam = "Plan_"
dt = Format(Now, "yyyy_mm_dd hmmAM/PM")
wbDest1 = ActiveWorkbook.Path
wbDest2 = "Your second location" 

For j = 1 To 2
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Choose(j, wbDest1, wbDest2) & "\" & wbNam & dt & ".xlsm"
Next j
```

This will save a copy of your workbook to two locations

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your response. I am getting runtime error 9 with this, any ideas? Sorry, should have also mentioned that both save locations are different to where the workbook template is saved. Thanks again

Comment: @SarahB What do your paths look like?

Comment: Path is on a work drive and is 9 folders deep. The other path hasn't yet been determined but I'm currently testing the code to ensure it works first. Is that what you meant? Apologies if I'm sounding a bit dim, I'm new to this! For wbdest1 and wbdest2 I added both separate filepaths for each. Thanks

Comment: Where is it throwing the error? Is it on the first or second loop?

Comment: Ah, I've managed to get it to work now! Wonderful! Thank you so much for your kind assistance!

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: No idea to be honest, I closed down and reopened, copied and pasted the code and filepaths again, and hey presto. Most odd. Perhaps I'd neglected to add the full filepaths, who knows? Many thanks again